# unable to forward pages in php

Tags: php

I have a php page. when users click on edit button then my all other fields data is apperaing the respective textbox, and also if he submits the form my data is updating. But my problem is it is not forwarding to my respected page.

i denoted it like this `header('Location: /profile.php');` for forwarding it in my profile page
What could be the reason?

My full code:

```
  <?php
                    include '../../../include/connection.php';
                    $idd =$_REQUEST['id'];
                    $resultt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM budget  WHERE budget_id = '$idd'");
                    $test = mysql_fetch_array($resultt);
                     if (!$resultt)
                        {
                            die("Error:<font color='red'> Data not found..</font>");
                        }
                    $budget_id=$test['budget_id'];
                    $heads_id=$test['heads_id'];
                    $amount= $test['amount'];
                    $from_date=$test['from_date'];
                    $to_date= $test['to_date'];

                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $headsid=$_POST['headsid'] ;
                        $amount= $_POST['amount'] ;
                        $todate=$_POST['todate'] ;
                        $frmdate= $_POST['frmdate'] ;
                        mysql_query("UPDATE budget SET heads_id ='$headsid',amount ='$amount',from_date ='$frmdate' ,to_date ='$todate',updater_id ='$uid',updated_date=NOW()  WHERE budget_id = '$idd'")
                                or die(mysql_error());
                        header('Location: /profile.php');// PROBLEM HERE UNABLE TO FORWARD TO THE PAGE
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: Have you verified that `$_POST['submit']` is set?  Try posting the form to a `phpinfo()` page to make sure.

Comment: Unable to forward this page ? Is it you are getting 404 error page not found or redirect it self is not happening

Comment: @Devesh it is still in the same page,with out changing my url

Comment: @Ashutosh are u trying to redirect it after a button is presS?

Comment: @Kaii i have already mention in my question. i want to redirect my page if submit button from my page is pressed after performing its action

Comment: @Ashutosh sorry for that and thanks

Comment: put the redirect logic as the first line and check if you are getting redirected . If yes then we have to see if you are getting error before Redirect is called

Comment: @Devesh  i already tried this, same problem

Answer (score 0):

strip or remove the backslash.

```
 header("Location: http://example.com/path/path/profile.php");
 exit;
```

Comment: try to put the whole path instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: profile.php');
die;
```

Comment: i tried but, page is comming as blank my url is not changing, it is still remaining the same